# Whenever I try to open minecraft.jar with openJDK it doesn't work

Tags: openjdk, minecraft

I tried right clicking and selecting open with JDK but nothing happens

Comment: Hmm, that should work I think.  From the command-line, change to the directory where you have the jar file via `cd /home/Mbbbackus/Downloads` or where ever and then try `java -jar minecraft.jar`.  Does that work?

Comment: What happen if you try to run this? java -jar minecraft.jar Do you have permission for that file? Do you have Java runtime installed?

Comment: Also when I last checked, Minecraft was not compatible with Java 7 (at least on Ubuntu). There was no error, it just wouldn't start. So please try running this with java version 6 which I can confirm works on Ubuntu perfectly.

Comment: There is a known bug in Precise (12.04, currently still in alpha) regarding Mimecraft. What version of Ubuntu are you running? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/935296 As requested by ninjascorner, open a terminal, `cd` to your Mimecraft directory and run `java -jar mimecraft.jar` and post the results into your question.